# Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp.fetch HTTP PUT Request to firebase not working

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase

I'm trying to write data to a firebase database using Google Apps Script HTTP PUT Request.  Here is what I have for code.  I've debugged every line and everything works except for the actual PUT request.

Web page with one button in it.

```
<section>
    <input onclick="WriteInput()" type="button" value="Save Input">
</section>

<script>
 function onSuccess() {
  alert("on success ran");

};

function onFailure() {
  alert("on failure ran");

};

function WriteInput() {
  alert("it ran");
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .putToFire();
}

</script>
```

This is the server side .gs code:

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WriteToFirebase')
        .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the NATIVE mode
        .setTitle('Test Write')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function putToFire() {
   
   var payload =
   {
     "first" : "Jack",
     "last" : "Sparrow"
   };
   
    var options =
    {
     "method" : "put",
     "payload" : payload
     };
 
  
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/fred/name.json", options );
 
    Logger.log(options);

   }
```

This is the Google documentation for issuing a HTTP request with Apps Script:

[fetch url Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String,Object%29)

This is the Firebase REST API documentation:

[Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html)

in `cURL -X` is to set the type of request.  E.g. PUT, POST, etc and `-d` is the indicate that data is to follow:  The match up with Google `Fetch` is to set the `params`.

I must be just missing a syntax setting or something.

Comment: What error are you receiving? Right now this just says "everything works but"; what exactly happens? What HTTP status code/error are returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found an answer to my problem.  I can't remember what the error message was.  I changed

**THIS:**

```
var options =
{
 "method" : "put",
 "payload" : payload
 };
```

**TO THIS:**

```
var options = {"method" : "put", "payload" : payload};
```

And it started working.  I'm guessing that the multi-line code had `end of line` `return` characters in it, that Firebase would not parse.  That's just my guess.

This example shows `payload`, `options` and the `Apps Script` `UrlFetchApp.fetch` service.

```
var payload = "{\"aa\" : \"" + UserID + "\", \"ab\" : \"" + Maker + "\", \"ac\" : " +
    AskingPrice + ", \"ad\" : \"" + Type +
    "\", \"ae\" : \"" + Description + "\", \"af\" : \"" + Function + "\", \"ag\" : \"" + 
    Cosmetic + "\", \"ah\" : \"" + dbID +
    "\", \"ai\" : \"" + IPaddr + "\"}";

var options = {"method" : "put", "payload" : payload};

UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://MyFireBaseDatabaseName.com/" + Ctgry + "/" 
+ dbID + "/.json", options );
```

Comment: But how could newlines in the source code influence serialization of the structure to JSON by the UrlFetchApp?